# Array Sorting - Optimizing Machining Schedule based on Tool Changes

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, mathematical-optimization

We have a set of work orders (each work order has a certain part number. Ex: Work Order 40 has 20 ct of part 1234, Work Order 41 has 35 ct of part 2351, etc.) that we need to run through a machine. There are multiple pieces of tooling used for machining each part. When moving from one part number to another part number, we may or may not need to swap out the tooling used.

Ex: this machine and the operations we are performing require three pieces of tooling: a base plate, grippers, and a clamp.

Part 1234 uses base plate 1, gripper 1, and clamp 1
Part 2351 uses base plate 1, gripper 2, and clamp 1
Part 4562 uses base plate 2, gripper 1, and clamp 2
...

So, if we wanted to machine part 1234 before or after 2351, we would have to change the grippers. If we wanted to machine part 2351 before or after part 4562, we would have to change plates, grippers, and clamps.

Each tool change has a fixed amount of time. Base plate may take 5 minutes to change, grippers may take 10 minutes, and clamps may take 2 minutes.

Now, the question is: **based on these tool changes, what is the optimal order to organize the work orders?** Obviously we would want to combine work orders that have the same part number (machine three work orders back-to-back-to-back that have part 1234 because then there would be no tool change time).

What sorting algorithm would be effective in this case?

Comment: I doubt any sorting algorithm can help you find an optimal solution here. Perhaps for a heuristic solution. From the description, it appears to be a sequence dependent setup time multiple nonidentical (?) machine scheduling problem with possibly precedence constraints also thrown into the mix. These are well known to be very difficult NP Hard problems. Also, you fail to mention what the optimality criterion is. Is it makespan? Is it some sort of weighted completion time of each jobs? For some objective functions, there could be polynomial time solution methods.

Comment: This is a Job-Shop scheduling problem, which is one application of mathematical programming.  It has been **extensively** studied and there are all kinds of books, etc. on subj.  There are all kinds of nuances:  tool changes (you mention), job sequencing, scoring by least tardy, makespan, etc. which dictate the right approach & structure.  If this is a real world application, and not an exercise, you'd probably be well served to hire a consultant with Job-Shop experience.  That said, I'm voting to close this because of lack of focus.